# Metadata of a Spark DataFrame (RDD)

Tags: r, apache-spark, benchmarking, sparkr, sparklyr

I am benchmarking spark in R via "sparklyr" and "SparkR". I test different functions on different Testdata. In two particular cases, where I count the amount of zeros in a column and the amount of NA's in a column, I realized that no matter how big the data is, the result is there in less than a second. All the other computations scale with the size of the data. 
So I don't think that Spark computes anything there, but that those cases are stored somewhere in the meta data, and that it computed these results while loading the data. I tested my functions and they always give me the right result.

Can anyone confirm whether the number of zeros and number of nulls in a column is stored in a dataframe's metadata, and if not, why does it return so quickly with the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no metadata associated to a Spark DataFrame that would contain columnar data; therefore, my guess is that the performance difference you measured is caused by something else. Hard to tell without a reproducible example.